# UINavigationItem titleView "ignored if leftBarButtonItem is set"?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

The documentation for UINavigationItem's `titleView` property [says](https://web.archive.org/web/20140807135258/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/titleView):

> "This property is ignored if `leftBarButtonItem` is not nil."

However, I've set both the `titleView` and `leftBarButtonItem` properties in my testing and they both appear to show up fine. I've tested on all the simulators in my Xcode: 4.3, 5.0, and 5.1. Does anyone know if the documentation is just wrong, or is it correct on some older versions (e.g. 4.2, 3.x) that I haven't been able to test?

Comment: Newer doc has this documentation error fixed: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624935-titleview

Answer (score 8):

Check the documentation for property [leftBarButtonItems](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/leftBarButtonItems), it says:

> If there is not enough room to display all of the items in the array,
>   those that would *overlap the title view (if present)* or the buttons
>   on the right side of the bar are not displayed.

So, what's said for `titleView` is probably incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

I think the documentation is wrong, and you should file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on iOS6.1 and iOS7. My UINavigationItem had a non-nil titleView and leftBarButtonItem, and both the titleView and leftBarButtonItem were visible. I filed a radar.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this as well. In My specific problem both the titleview and leftbar item would appear. However If I had a Back Button then my titleview would disappear on Push and use the default title. If I have a custom uibuttonitem set for the left it works fine. So It seems to be related to back button. I ended up solving by setting title attributes and no doing a custom view.

Answer (score -1):

I just ran into this and found the same thing you did. I also noted that the documentation for UINavigationItem was last updated in 2011, while UINavigationBar got updates in both iOS 5 and 6, so it's possible this behavior changed since the last time the UINavigationItem doc was updated.

Very confusing though.

Noticed this as well in UINavigationController's reference:

> "The navigation controller updates the middle of the navigation bar as follows:
>
> ...
>
> If the new top-level view controller has a custom title view, the navigation bar displays that view in place of the default title view. To specify a custom title view, set the titleView property of the view controller’s navigation item."

Since there's a leftBarByButton (the back button) by definition anytime you're at the non-root view, it sure seems like a mistake in the UINavigationItem's documentation