# How to customize UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I'm struggling in **custom UINavigationBar**. The reason i want to customize is because there is same action that can be occur in different view controller. I post some images as an example.

[image: Navigation Bar - 1]
[image: Navigation Bar - 2]
[image: Navigation Bar - 3]

As you can see from the images above. I think you get what i mean. I have been trying and searching, but i don't get the answer i wanted. Furthermore, i have tried using **UIView** to accomplish this, it worked, but i don't think it is correct way to do this. Therefore, i need help from you guys to lead me to the right path. :) :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom title view to the navigation bar like this way.

```
//To hide default back button
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;

//Title View for Navigation
UIView *navTitle1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
[navTitle1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

//Left View button and separator
UIButton *backBarButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 44)];
[backBarButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIView *ttlview1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(51, 0, 1, 44)];
[ttlview1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];


//Center view with two buttons and seprator for them
UIView *middleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 121, 44)];
[middleView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[middleView setCenter:navTitle1.center];

UIButton *postBarButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 44)];
[postBarButton setTitle:@"Post" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIView *ttlview2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(middleView.frame.size.width/2, 0, 1, 44)];
[ttlview2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

UIButton *memeBarButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((middleView.frame.size.width/2)+1, 0, 60, 44)];
[memeBarButton setTitle:@"Meme" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[middleView addSubview:ttlview2];
[middleView addSubview:postBarButton];
[middleView addSubview:memeBarButton];

//Right button with seprator before that
UIView *ttlview3 = [[UIView alloc]     initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-71, 0, 1, 44)];
[ttlview3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
```

You can refer [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664778/creating-a-uibarbutton-centered-programmatically/29665257#29665257) for more detail.

Comment: This is what i done before. Is this the correct to do it instead of customizing.

Comment: I think, this is the the way, you can do high level of customisation, Default Navigation bar not providing to do this kind of customisation directly through native functions and button.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 custom UIBarButtonItem from 2 views, using this document:

From Apple documentation:
    Initializes a new item using the specified custom view.

```
- (id)initWithCustomView:(UIView *)customView
```

Parameters **customView**: A custom view representing the item.
Return Value Newly initialized item with the specified properties.

- Left bar item: 1 view contains 3 buttons: Project, Kiara Paradize, Artist Impression.
- Right bar item: 1 view contains 4 buttons: Sign up | Login (Profile button when user logged in) | Hamburger menu

Then:

- self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem from left
  Custom View
- self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem from right Custom View