# Align UIBarButtonItem Title to prevent overlapping of other Buttons?

Tags: ios, user-interface, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

I want to create a header toolbar like shown in the image below. It is from the web view of the Twitter app.

[image]

I created a `UIToolbar` and put it at the top. Then I inserted the Buttons left and right and changed the Identifier to get the correct symbols.

My problem is the text in the middle. I create a `UIBarButtonItem` and placed it between the buttons. Here is my Problem.

- How to I achieve that the UIBarButtonItem title does not overlap the left and the right button when the title is to long?

In my case:

[image]

- How do I achieve that the title gets `...` at the end if it gets to long?
- How can I set the sub title?
- How can I achieve that the button is not clickable, i.e., has color black?

Edit Using the answer from @Viral Savaj: Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set custom title view to the navigation bar like this way.

```
//To hide default back button
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;

//Title View for Navigation
UIView *navTitle1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
[navTitle1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

//Left View button and separator
UIButton *crossBarButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
[crossBarButton setTitle:@"X" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//Center view with two buttons and seprator for them
UILabel *topTitle =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(50,0, self.view.bounds.size.width-100, 22)];
topTitle.text = @"text"; 
topTitle.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:25];
topTitle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;


UILabel *subTitle =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(50,20, self.view.bounds.size.width-100, 18)];
subTitle.text = @"subtext"; 
subTitle.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
subTitle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;

//Right button with seprator before that
UIButton *uploadBarButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-50, 0, 44, 44)];
[uploadBarButton setTitle:@"U" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


[navTitle1 addSubview:crossBarButton];
[navTitle1 addSubview:topTitle];
[navTitle1 addSubview:subTitle];
[navTitle1 addSubview:uploadBarButton];
self.navigationItem.titleView = navTitle1;
```

You can refer [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664778/creating-a-uibarbutton-centered-programmatically/29665257#29665257) for more detail.

Comment: How can I achieve that the button is not clickable, i.e., has color black?

Comment: @stephan1001 regarding which button you are talking, If you are talking about `crossBarButton`,`uploadBarButton`, then you can set `[crossBarButton setEnabled:NO];` and set color of that button by `[crossBarButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: Should I use a NavigationBar, a ToolBar or a custom UIView for my purpose?

Comment: @stephan1001 Just Embed NavigationController to your ViewController, from menu "Editor->Embed In->Navigation Control", then Put this code in ViewController's viewdidload method And It works.

Comment: I will accept your answer there are just a few more questions please see my last edit. 1) Why does the  navTitle1 has a margin left and right? 2) How do I get the header semi transparent?

Answer (score 1):

1. To test if the title is too long, you should use character counting. Let `myHeaderBarString` represent your string for the title. You will probably have to adjust this number to find the right length before it gets truncated.

> ```
> if count(myHeaderBarString) > 40 {
>
> myHeaderBarString = myHeaderBarString.substringToIndex(40)
>  myHeaderBarString.append("...") 
>
> }
> ```

For a subtitle, you should insert a new view with a UILabel inside it.

Comment: This is no good, since you'd only be tailoring the look for one aspect ratio and screen size.

Comment: this is a quick solution, the best one would be to relate it to screen width and font size.

Answer (score 0):

Use `BarButtonItem.customView`, it works.

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,200,40))

button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

button.setTitle("gogogogogogogogoogogogogogogogogogoogo", forState: .Normal)

button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)

button.addTarget(self, action: "showMessage:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

let rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()

rightBarButtonItem.customView = button

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem
```