# How can I change size of UINavigationItem's leftBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I want to change the size of leftBarButtonItem.
If I go with custom barButtonItem then I would not get the sign of previous on that button.

Here I got success to make small text via setting following code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:
     @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But sign of previous is not changing.

[image]

Is there any way (other-than set image) to make small that sign?
I have also tried to change scale of that `leftBarButtonItem` but there is not method available to do so.

Comment: Would you like to set custom NavigationBar??, if yes, the refere http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664778/creating-a-uibarbutton-centered-programmatically/29665257#29665257

Comment: @ViralSavaj, I have no problem to set custom but May I able to get previous sign in custom button?

Comment: If you like to show ( < ) previous then you have to make one image for that ans set Image of back button, if don;t want then no need at all.

Comment: Its better to create a custom button

Comment: Agree with @SKT,  you can simple add custom button to Navigationbar also.

Comment: No, Change the size of Image of default previous button, in navigation controller is not possible,

Answer (score 1):

```
UIView *viewLeftSide = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 30.0)];
viewLeftSide.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UIButton *btn1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 5.0, 20.0, 20.0)];
[btn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(sel1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[viewLeftSide addSubview:btn1];

UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0, 5.0, 20.0, 20.0)];
[btn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(sel2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[viewLeftSide addSubview:btn2];

UIBarButtonItem *leftBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:viewLeftSide];

self.tabBarController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIBarButtonItem* backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(barButtonBackPressed:)];


UIImage *backImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backarrow11.png"];
UIButton *back = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
back.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 17, 17);
[back setImage:backImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[back addTarget:self action:@selector(barButtonBackPressed:)forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *barBtn2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:back];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:barBtn2,backButton, nil];
```